# Extend flat cable between LCD panel and driver board

Tags: lcd, cables, display, ffc

Given a setup similar to this: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2395
The panel itself is nicely thin, but the driver board takes up some space. So I need to put it somewhere separate from the display. Is there a way of extending those FFC cables to about 1-2 meters? Preferably using a non flat cable.

Comment: Those cables carry reasonably high bandwidth signals (not as fast as HDMI, but still), provided you use something like a ribbon cable (that flat flex *is* effectively a ribbon cable anyway), it may be alright, but several meters may be pushing things. If you can afford to, try it and see, you never know, it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flat Flex cables used with LCD panels are usually custom-made, and sometimes even carry some components like filtering caps and resistors. I'm pretty sure they don't sell such cables with a custom length. You could order custom cables to be produced, but that only makes sense if you need hundreds of them. So no, I don't see a way to achieve this in a hobby project like yours.

Edit:

The link you have provided in comments shows an LCD display which seems to use a standard FFC cable. If this is the case, you could buy such LCD with an extension cable, then buy a longer extension cable. Standard FFC cables are commonly available up to lengths of 500-600mm, you may find a longer one if you're lucky. Of course, Tom's comment still applies: you may get a reduced image quality, visual artifacts, or a non-working display when using a long extension cable, but it's worth trying.

Comment: What is the problem with these components if I don't replace the cable but extend it?

Comment: They may be dimensioned for a given cable length. But more importantly, how do you plan to extend the cable?

Comment: I just found this, which is very similar to the product I mentioned above, but has an extension included (not very long, but still): https://www.amazon.de/Tontec%C2%AE-Resolution-EJ070NA-01J-Fernfahrer-Raspberry/dp/B00QK77K28/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1464701202&sr=8-8&keywords=7-Zoll-HDMI-Monitor

Comment: Well, you could buy that one if it suits you more. Or you could make that extra adapter board for the display you already have, if you know how to route PCBs and happen to have a reflow oven at home.

Comment: You don't need an over for this.  Flat flex connectors can be soldered with an iron.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The ones used with LCDs usually have 0.5mm pitch. I don't say it's impossible to solder them with an iron, but it far from easy, and you still need to design a custom PCB.

Comment: Pin pitch is not very relevant to iron solderability - the hard work of getting the right connections is done by surface tension and flux, and best results are often had with a tip substantially larger than the individual pins.  The PCB is a fairly easy one to design, just consisting of parallel lines, potentially iron transferred from a laser printout that need not even be made with PCB design software.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm sorry to derive from the topic, but how do you remove a solder blob shorting two pins together? I find it practically impossible to solder 40 pins in a row without making a single accidental solder blob.

Comment: Indeed, one should plan for mistakes - get a roll of the narrow desolder braid, and have flux available to improve its performance.  In some cases simply by fluxing you can wipe the excess away from the pins in the direction of traces, but care is needed on etched boards as quarter-millimeter traces lift quite easily.  And of course the process starts by soldering one pin, checking alignment, soldering another at the other end, rechecking, and only then soldering the intermediate ones.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hey, thanks! I didn't know about solder braid, I'm going to try it out next time.

Comment: It can be wonderful stuff - though I didn't realize that for a long time as the very wide version they used to sell at retail stores takes an absurd amount of heat and isn't very useful for surface mount work.  Also without adequate flux (in the braid or added) it may not seem to do much.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fast signals are used in your particular application, the cable inductance and skew of the signal might be a problem. 2 meters might still be ok but if it's high speed, you can quickly go out of specification and loose the picture or have artifacts/dropout on your screen. Flat cables are there for a reason but it's entirely possible to make a round one that have all pairs twisted and separated and/or shielded as needed. Look at the cross section of a normal network CAT5 versus CAT6 cable and you will see what I'm talking about. That's a reasonably fast signal in a round cable.

But you will not break anything if you go ahead and test it. If the protocol, driver and receiver is forgiving or the speed is just low, you could get away with it.